# Trello API authentication not giving a valid user token if I disconnect

Tags: javascript, api, symfony, trello, authorize

I integrated trello API to my dashboard on symfony 3.4.

When I go to my page for the first time, I have the `authorize()` function as a popup. When I accept, I have my token and my boards as return. For this case, all is good.

But if I disconnect the current user and come with another, this new user can access to the previous boards. It's like if the token stay the first user how come on the navigator.

**Authorize()**

```
Trello.authorize({
    name : 'Native Web',
    type : 'popup',
    expiration: "never",
    success: function () { onAuthorizeSuccessful(); },
    error: function () { onFailedAuthorization(); },
    scope: { write: true, read: true },
});
```

**onAuthorizeSuccessful()**

```
function onAuthorizeSuccessful() {
    var token = Trello.token();
    Trello.get('/members/me/boards/', successBoards, error);
}
```

The `successBoards` function processes the data.

So, do you have an idea? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As far as disconnecting the user, what exactly are you doing? Where are you storing the token?

Comment: I'm not storing in my database, just on my session... So i see my error... I need to store the token, and take a call with the token of users. And if they haven't token or if they remove the access, re ask the authorize. I will try all of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's done, i have save the token on cookie. And i call Trello.authorize if the cookie doesn't exist.

I have added persist: false on this function. Like that the token is not save by the trello logic, but by my logic.

If someone is in my case :

**Authorize()**

```
 Trello.authorize({
            name: 'Native Web',
            type: 'popup',
            persist: false,
            expiration: "never",
            success: function () {
                onAuthorizeSuccessful();
            },
            error: function () {
                onFailedAuthorization();
            },
            scope: {write: true, read: true},
        });
```

**onAuthorizeSuccessful()**

```
function onAuthorizeSuccessful() {
    var token = Trello.token();
    $.cookie($.cookie('currentLog')+'TokenTrello', token, {expires: 365, secure: false});
    loadBoards();
}
```

**loadBoards()**

```
function loadBoards() {
    //Get the users boards
    $.get('https://api.trello.com/1/members/me/boards?key=' + API_KEY + '&token=' + $.cookie($.cookie('currentLog')+'TokenTrello'), successBoards);
}
```

Solved for me. Thanks